# seaborn subplots keep different x labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to keep the order of x labels of 2 sub barplots.
The issue is, when I run the script, the second subplot labels update the first one, so that it falsifies values...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"myindex":["Tuesday", "Thursday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], "myvalues":[20000,18000,16000,12000, 10000]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"myindex":["Tuesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", "Wednesday"], "myvalues":[600,580,350,200,150]})
f, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12), ncols=2, sharex=True)
sns.despine(left=True)

x, y1 = np.array(df1.myindex), (df1.myvalues)
g1 = sns.barplot(x, y1, ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_xticklabels(labels=x, rotation=90)

x, y1 = np.array(df2.myvalues), (df2.myvalues)
g2 = sns.barplot(x, y1, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_xticklabels(labels=x, rotation=90)
```

This is due to the `set_xticklabels` function which I think, is not appropriate to set `x` labels for two subplots.
Hence, labels of `1st` plot have to be : `["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]`, whereas labels of `2nd` plot have to be : `["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Monday"]`. However at the end, labels of `1st` plot are equivalent to labels of `2nd` plot...

Comment: What about a  [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this is coming soon

Comment: Remove `sharex = True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the figure you are specifying that the axes share the x axis using `sharex = True`. This means that which ever call to `axes.set_tickslabels()` you make *last* will appear on both plots.

The solution is to remove `sharex=True` from the figure initialisation. A full example with some fake data:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12), ncols=2)
sns.despine(left=True)

x1 = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"]
y1 = [5,2,6,8]
g1 = sns.barplot(x1, y1, ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_xticklabels(labels=x1, rotation=90)

x2 = [2,65,9,0]
y2 = [5,2,6,8]
g2 = sns.barplot(x2, y2, ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_xticklabels(labels=x2, rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: absolutly true. Morality: never add an argument without verifying its effect